# How can I attach the debugger to an Angular Docker container in VS Code?

Tags: angular, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm the 1'000'000 dev to aks this question, but i could not find the solution. How can i attach the VSCode debugger to a running angular application inside a docker container? How should the `launch.json` look like to get this to work? Horteloading and starting the app works just fine.

I'm running vscode via ssh on a remote linux dev-server.

I've following setup:

```
├ server
│   ├ server.csproj
│   ├ Dockerfile
│   ├ ...
├ client
│   ├ src
│   │   ├ ...
│   ├ Dockerfile
│   ├ package.json
├ docker-compose.yml
```

The .Net Application works like a charm, but i'm not able to attach the debuger to the `Client` container.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
  client:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./client
      target: debug
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./client:/src
      - ./client/node_modules:/src/node_modules
```

**Angular Dockerfile**

```
# Development Container
FROM node:18-alpine as debug
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "run", "start-dev" ]

# Build Container
FROM node:18-alpine as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
RUN npm run build --prod

# Prod Container
FROM nginx:alpine as pord
COPY --from=build /src/dist/client /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "remoteRoot": "/src/",
            "port": 9229,
            "address": "localhost",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client/src/",
            "restart": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "start-dev": "ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  }
}
```

To start the container I build and start the container as following:

```
docker compose build client
docker compose up client
```

Exposing the debug port 9229 (Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml) i get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint client (5cacc05b4977a019742e3d4670302211b2aef037b0332331f3166a5678c3e900): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:9229: bind: address already in use
```